# Android App Bundle firmado con un certificado restringido

Tags: android, app, certificado

Estoy intentando subir mi primer app a Play Store, pero al momento de hacerlo me lanza el siguiente error:

> Subiste un archivo APK o Android App Bundle firmado con un certificado
> restringido. Debes subir un archivo APK o Android App Bundle firmado
> con tu propio certificado.

Segui los pasos segun documentacion y muchos tutoriales sobre la firma pero aun asi no logre subirla.
Alguien tiene idea de que podria ser el problema?
Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Probablemente estás tratando de subir una actualización de tu aplicación. Cuando subes una aplicación, esta y sus siguientes actualizaciones deben ser firmadas con el mismo certificado (clave de firma), no podrás subir una actualización con un certificado diferente, es por esto que debes guardar el certificado que creaste.

Si no cuentas con el certificado no podrás subir una actualización, tendrás que subir una nueva aplicación en la cual debes cambiar su "package name".

Revisa la documentación:
[Como firmar tu app Android](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing)

> Si tu app ya está firmada y publicada en Google Play Store con una
> clave de firma de la app existente, o si deseas usar una clave de
> firma de la app para una app nueva en lugar de la que crea Google,
> puedes generarla mediante los siguientes pasos:
>
> - [Firma tu app](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#sign_release) con la clave de firma de la app y selecciona la opción para encriptar y exportar la clave de firma.
> - [Sube la clave de firma de la app](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#upload_signing_key) a la firma de apps de Play.
> - Recomendación: [Genera y registra un certificado de carga](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#generate-key) para actualizaciones futuras de tu app.
> - [Sube la app a Google Play.](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/upload-bundle)
> - [Prepara e implementa el lanzamiento de la app.](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7159011)

---

**Si tu aplicaciòn es la primera que subes y obtienes este error, esto indica que estas tratando de subir tu APK o Android App Bundle sin firmarlo con un certificado (clave de firma) valido**.

Revisa:
[**Genera una clave de carga y un almacén de claves.**](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing?hl=es-419#sign-apk)

Si todavía no tienes una clave de carga, que sirve para configurar la firma de apps de Play, puedes generar una con Android Studio de la siguiente manera:

- En la barra de menú, haz clic en B**uild > Generate Signed Bundle/APK**
- En el diálogo **Generate Signed Bundle or APK**, selecciona **Android App Bundle** o **APK**, y haz clic en **Next**.
- En el campo **Key store path**, haz clic en **Create new**.
- En la ventana **New Key Store**, proporciona la siguiente información para el almacén de claves y la clave, como se muestra en la imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Figura 2: Crea una clave de carga y un almacén de claves nuevos en Android Studio

- **Almacén de claves**

**Key store path:** Selecciona la ubicación en la que quieras crear el almacén de claves. Además, se debe agregar un nombre de archivo al final de la ruta de acceso de ubicación con la extensión .jks.
**Password:** Crea y confirma una contraseña segura para el almacén de claves.

- Clave

**Alias:** Ingresa un nombre de identificación para la clave.
**Password:** Crea y confirma una contraseña segura para tu clave. Debe ser la misma que la contraseña del almacén de claves. (Consulta el [problema conocido](https://developer.android.com/studio/known-issues?hl=es-419#ki-key-keystore-warning) para obtener más información).
**Validity (years):** Establece durante cuántos años será válida la clave. Debe ser válida durante al menos 25 años para que puedas firmar actualizaciones con la misma clave durante todo el ciclo de vida de la app.
**Certificate:** ingresa información acerca de ti para el certificado. Esta información no se muestra en la app, pero se incluye en el certificado como parte del APK.

- Una vez que completes el formulario, haz clic en **OK**.

Si deseas compilar y firmar la app con la clave de carga, continúa con la sección [Cómo firmar tu app con la clave de carga](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing?hl=es-419#sign_release). Si solo deseas generar la clave y el almacén de claves, haz clic en **Cancel**.

Comment: Es la primer app que intento subir, no tengo versiones anteriores

Comment: Ok, entonces tratas de subir directamente el .apk o .aab, este de forma predeterminada se firma con un certificado de "debug", debes crear uno, revisa la actualizaciòn de mi respuesta.